# Unity 2.1 configuration

Tags: configuration, unity-container

I'm trying to find any documentation on Unity configuration but it now seems that this is only available up to version 2.0? I'm getting version 2.1 through NuGet and the configuration just seems to be different...

e.g. `<register />` is done using `<type />` in Unity 2.1? **Is there any documentation available on Unity 2.1 configuration?**

**Unity 2.0:**

```
<register type="IInterfaceAlias" mapTo="ClassAlias">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
```

**Unity 2.1:**

```
<type type="IInterfaceAlias" mapTo="ClassAlias">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
```

Thanks for clearing up anybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 2.1 is just a maintenance release. Nothing changed regarding how to configure the container from v2.0

Comment: Ok, i tried changing the `type` elements to `register` and it still works. Is the XML schema for configuration flexible (read: it queries by attributes instead of element names?)